# Prevent click event for wrapper when inner link is click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the example for UI element construct,

**HTML**

```
  <div class='wrap'>
          <a class='inner-link' href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap
{
  background:#CDD4E0;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  padding:20px;
}

.wrap:hover
{
  background:#868B93;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
   $('.wrap').click(function () {
             alert("Handler for wrap container click.");
         });
         
   $('.inner-link').click(function () {
             alert("Handler for inner link click");
         });
```

What I want to do is to prevent the container with the class `.wrap` click event when I click the link inside.
You can reference this [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tu3n0e7p/).
Current code fire `$('.wrap').click` when I do for `$('.inner-link').click`.

Comment: Do you mean when the user clicks the link, then it will not alert("Handler for wrap container click.")

Comment: @tzhong0411, yes correct. I want to prevent it.

Comment: Use `e.stopPropagation()` as in https://jsfiddle.net/cw610y2x/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `if` to check if the target does not contain class `inner-link`.

UPDATE: Oh, the comment has a better way to solve it.

```js
$(".wrap").click(function (e) {
  if (e.target.className !== "inner-link") { // add this
    alert("Handler for wrap container click.");
  }
});

$(".inner-link").click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); // or add this
  alert("Handler for inner link click");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Your jQuery codes should be modified as below:

```
$('.wrap').click(function () {
  alert("Handler for wrap container click.");
});

$('.inner-link').click(function (event) {
  event.stopPropogation();
  alert("Handler for inner link click");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks @riceEater for the idea with the class. I solved it with this:

```
var elem = $('.parentElem');
elem.on("click",function(e) {
  var hitElementClass = e.target.className;
  if (hitElementClass.includes("my-wrapper-class")) {
    elem.find("input").trigger("click");
  }
});
```